# Infinite loop on .hasNext()

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to read a file and extract the largest number. I want to read the file till the end but hasNext() keeps giving me true. When I tried changing this to hasNextInt(), it never went in even when my characters where integers. How can I get out of the loop and read my integers correctly? Help would be much appreciated.

```
int maxScore=0;
        int score = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner("PacManHighScore");
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
                score = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(score);
            if(score > maxScore) {
                maxScore = score;
            }
        }
        scan.close();
```

Comment: If the input is **not** an `int` you don't consume it. Thus you enter an infinite loop, checking to see if the same pending input is an `int` (it's not). `else { scan.nextLine(); continue; }` should fix that. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to skip non int value so you are stuck in an infinite loop.

Try the code below.

```
int maxScore=0;
int score = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner("PacManHighScore");
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
        score = scan.nextInt();
    }else{
        scan.next();
    }
    System.out.println(score);
    if(score > maxScore) {
        maxScore = score;
    }
}
scan.close();
```